Reverse leaving in Essbase
I need a script that reinstates a previously employee back into the workforce. I managed to develop a script for one year, but I now need it to also account for the following two years (for example, FY24 and FY25) in order to include the employee's restoration.
This is my current script, at present, however it solely brings to one year (FY24):
FIX ("OEP_Forecast", "OEP_Working", "EN1" ,"USD")

    FIX ("EMP1" ,"J1")
   
        FIX (FY24, @LEVMBRS( "Period", 0))
            FIX("No Property")
           
           "OWP_Start Month"(
             
             IF (("Yr-Index" == "Yr-Index"->{Year} and "Fiscal TP-Index" >= "Fiscal TP-Index"->@MEMBER(@CONCATENATE("HSP_ID_", @HspNumToString({Month})))) OR "Yr-Index" > "Yr-Index"->{Year})
             
              "OWP_Headcount" = 1;
              "OWP_FTE" = 1;
             
                    IF(@ISMBR({Year}))
                       
                      IF ("Fiscal TP-Index" >= "Fiscal TP-Index"->@MEMBER(@CONCATENATE("HSP_ID_", @HspNumToString({Month}))))
                        "OWP_Action" = 1;
                        "OWP_FTE" = 1;
                        "OWP_Start Month" = {Month};
                      ENDIF
                       
                    ENDIF
                       
               ENDIF
                 
             )
             ENDFIX
         ENDFIX
     ENDFIX
ENDFIX

